# Нужно ли читать 1-е, 2-е, 3-е издания книги перед прочтением 4-го издания?

Tags: книги

объясните такую вещь, в магазине продается книга
например "Философия Java 4-e издание", например.

вопрос. получается чтобы прочесть 4-е издание. чтобы было понятно, что к чему.
нужно прочесть 1-е, 2-е и 3-е издания? так?

т.е. 4-е издание - это продолжение уже пройденного? или просто доработка\изменения\дополнение, и поэтому называется: 1,2,3

и можно смело читать 4-е издания не читая 1,2,3

если сразу 4-е издание читать, и пропустить: 1,2,3. это ведь в корне неправильно так?

нужно компетентное мнение-ответ.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127094/discussion-on-question-by-pek9----1--2--3----).

Answer (score 2):

Компетентное мнение :)

Все развивается, меняется и т.д. Автор дополняет, исправляет, меняет свою книгу, делая ее лучше, современнее и т.д. Но книга при этом остается самодостаточной.

Т.е. если у вас есть возможность купить разные издания - лучше (в общем случае, бывают, увы, варианты... особенно при переводах...) брать самое последнее.

Читать предыдущие издания при этом совершенно не обязательно :)

P.S. Кстати, если бы вы скачали пару изданий некоторой книги и посмотрели тексты - то и вопроса бы такого у вас не было :)

P.P.S. Минуса выглядят просто смешно. Минусующие, покажите хоть одно N-е издание, которое требовало бы чтения N-1-го издания :) Особенно смешно, если учесть место моей работы :)

Answer (score -2):

Немного старенькая, изданная в 2006-м, энциклопедия Java, подробно описывает фичи Java 5. Изложение замкнуто, и от предыдущих изданий не зависит. То есть не требуется читать предыдущие издания, чтобы прочитать четвёртое.

Несмотря на почтенный возраст до сих пор читабельная книга. За прошедшие 15 лет экосистема Java развивалась в основном в библиотеках - монструозный Spring, куча кода в репозиториях Apache. Как язык Java изменился не очень сильно. Если вы освоите четвертое издание **Thinking in Java**, то вы узнаете почти всё о фундаменте Java - классы, интерфейсы, объекты, наследование, контейнеры, обобщенные типы, аннотации, перечисления, ввод-вывод, основы графики.

Чего в **Thinking in Java** нет. Где-то в районе Java 7 добавился оператор `<>`, примерно тогда же появились лямбда выражения, цикл `foreach`. Где-то в районе Java 11 появился вывод типа для локальных переменных (ключевое слово `var`). В области параллельной обработки добавили потоки (`streams`). В какой-то момент в Java ввели модули. Я не гарантирую, что перечислил всё, но основные новые фичи, по-моему, указал. По сравнению с тем, что у Эккеля есть, это меньше 10%.

Если прочтёте, станете натуральным экспертом в языке Java.

Однако лично я не стал бы читать этот талмудище, поискал бы книжки потоньше. Например третье издание **Effective Java**. Тоже не самый свежак, но хоть в три раза тоньше. Моя первая книга по Java, в которой описывалась Java 1.1, толщиной была меньше 200 страниц :)

Answer (score -3):

если учишь с нуля, то отложи книги на потом.
сначала скачай какие-нибудь курсы с торрентов либо посмотри уроки с ютуба.
и уже потом, когда что-то начнёшь понимать берись за книги.

я когда начал учить, сразу схватился за **эккеля философия джава** и прочитав 100 страниц меня поситила мысль , что программирование это не моё.

так что начни сначала с курсов и роликов, а книги читай потом, либо используй как дополнительный источник информации к уже пройденным темам.

я вот на днях купил б/у книжку (2.5$) по обьявлению **гудрич структуры данных и алгоритмы в java 2003г** читается весело и интересно. но если б я её сразу начал читать, я бы ни чего не понял.
так что не заморачивайся...

Comment: уроки с ютуба - а то, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcmUOmvl1N8

Comment: Вы должно быть не читали вопрос. Он совсем не про то, на что вы отвечаете )

Comment: @Kromster по большому счёту какая разница 3, 4 издание ? stack както поменялся, алгоритмы сортировки или ещё что-нибудь?

Comment: @ user7860670 если вам подобные уроки добавят каких знаний почему бы и нет.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XC8RmEn5gYA&list=PLlb7e2G7aSpQith1Z6xRpU8jFPgkh_Gvz&t=0s вот хорошие лекции. если поискать то можно найти

Comment: @pek9 я учу где-то 3й месяц, в свободное от работы время(не it)

Comment: @pek9 пожалуйста... главное - остерегайся злобных, и мстительных школьников, которые из под тишка, без обьективной критики минусуют вопросы и ответы)

Comment: @pek9 .... может быть.... вцелом книги нужны, мне вот легче видео формат воспринимать, ещё на mp3-шку записываю конференции по java и по дороге на работу слушаю. на компе читаю, но на много меня не хватает, 50 стр максимум. попробуй разные варианты и выбери как тебе удобней... а то , что там 3 или 4 издание это мелочи. это типо сделали в 12 джаве лямбду в switch выражении, и это надо добавить в книгу. основы они ж одинаковые что 1м что в 4м издании